# Show that the generalized function is a generalized solution to the equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, distribution-theory

Show that the generalized functions displayed on the right are generalized solutions in $\mathscr{D'}(\mathbb{R}^{1})$

$$x u' = p.v.(\frac{1}{x}), \quad u = c_{1} + c_{2} \theta(x) - p.v.(\frac{1}{x})$$

$$x^{2} u' = 1, \quad u = c_{1} + c_{2} \theta(x) + c_{3} \delta(x) - p.v.(\frac{1}{x}),$$

where $\theta(x)$ is Heaviside's function such that $\theta(x) = 1, x \geq 0$ and $\theta(x) = 0, x < 0$ and $\theta'(x) = \delta(x)$; where $\delta(x)$ is Dirac's delta function.

I am confused about what precisely the problem asks and especially by the notations $x u'$ and $x^{2} u'$.

As I understand it is just derive $u$ and set into the respective equations i.e. for the first one it would be $u' = \frac{d}{dx} u = \theta'(x) + p.v.(\frac{1}{x^{2}})$.

And for the second we have $u' = \theta'(x) + \delta'(x) + p.v.(\frac{1}{x^{2}})$. But then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one:
$$
u = c_{1} + c_{2} \theta(x) - \text{pv}\frac{1}{x} \\
u' = c_{2} \delta(x) + \text{fp}\frac{1}{x^2} \\
xu' = c_{2} x \,\delta(x) + x \,\text{fp}\frac{1}{x^2} = \text{pv}\frac{1}{x} \\
$$

The second one:
$$
u = c_{1} + c_{2} \theta(x) + c_{3} \delta(x) - \text{pv}\frac{1}{x} \\
u' = c_{2} \delta(x) + c_{3} \delta'(x) + \text{fp}\frac{1}{x^2} \\
xu' = c_{2} x\,\delta(x) + c_{3} x\,\delta'(x) + x\,\text{fp}\frac{1}{x^2} 
= - c_{3} \delta(x) + \text{pv}\frac{1}{x} \\
x^2 u' = - c_{3} x\,  \delta(x) + x \, \text{pv}\frac{1}{x} = 1 \\
$$

Comment: What happens to the part when you multiply the derivative of $u$ by $x$? How does the $x$ disappear? What does it do to the functions that they disappear?

Comment: Is it because multiplication by a function is $\langle x f, \phi \rangle := \langle f, x \phi \rangle$ and then i.e. for the p.v. of $\frac{1}{x^{2}}$ the $x$ cancels with the $x^{2}$ within the integral of the p.v., leaving the p.v. of $\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: @sloupo. What part are you referring to?

Comment: I.e. for the second one $u' = c_{2} \delta(x) + c_{3} \delta '(x) + fp \frac{1}{x^{2}}$. Then $xu' = c_{2} x \delta(x) + c_{3} x \delta '(x) + x fp \frac{1}{x^{2}}$. How does this imply the next equality. Is it because how the multiplication of a generalized function by a function is defined and then within the integral the $x$ cancels with the fraction of the p.v.?

Comment: @sloupo. Yes, $x\,\delta = 0$ and $x \, \text{fp}\frac{1}{x^2} = \text{pv}\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.